# Validating form input fields while typing using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var firstname = "/^[A-Za-z]+$/";
    var email = /^[ ]*([^@@\s]+)@@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})[ ]*$/i;

    jQuery('input#firstname').bind('input propertychange', function() {
        if (firstname.test(jQuery(this).val())) {
            jQuery(this).css({
                'background': '#C2D699'
            });
        } else {
            jQuery(this).css({
                'background': '#FFC2C2'
            });
        }
    });

    jQuery('input#email').bind('input propertychange', function() {
        if (email.test(jQuery(this).val())) {
            jQuery(this).css({
                'background': '#C2D699'
            });
        } else {
            jQuery(this).css({
                'background': '#FFC2C2'
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

and in view i have two textboxes in my view:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.FirstName, new { id = "firstname", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "16" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Register.Email, new { id = "email", @class = "form-control", @type = "email" })
```

For email validation is working but for firstname its not..What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need quotes around `regex` of firstname.

```
var firstname = "/^[A-Za-z]+$/"; // string
//              ^             ^
```

Use:

```
var firstname = /^[A-Za-z]+$/; // `regex`
```

Comment: Thats it...tnx...i cant accept your answer for 8 more minutes but i will :)